# Schedule mysql event to run every chosen day of the week

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

i want to read my table `logs` after rotating my logs using an event and i want my event to run in any day of the week i choose.

After doing some research,i have come up with this

```
CREATE EVENT read_rotated_logs
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 WEEK
  STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
    DO BEGIN

    END */$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Its not clear how i might arrive at a specific day of the week for example monday.How may i structure my code to make the event run on any speific day of the week `(mon or tuesday or wednesday or thursday or friday or saturday or sunday)`

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Event/Eventscheduleeveryweek.htm

Comment: I have just written this `select dayofweek(curdate());` from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek looks promising.Let me study the link,looks interesting.

Comment: @Mihai In the link,its as if mysql has a notion of days of the week like in the ordinary English Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you do it for the other days of the week

Monday

```
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 0 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
```

Tuesday

```
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY
```

and so on

Comment: Hi,how do i add a specific time on `STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY`

Comment: you can do something like this `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 7 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR` and play with  + INTERVAL 1 HOUR to be on your desired hour

Comment: Isn't there any way to set the time explicitly like `11:00 a.m`?

Comment: you can try like this `CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY,' 11:00:00')`

Comment: Is it mandatory for time in an event to be in 24 hour format?.